# Webservices in asp.net and app pool recycling

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, application-pool

I'm having a hard time phrasing this question in searches to get relevant answer so I'm trying here. I have a long task, a data sync between two applications, one of them being an asp.net website. I wanted to have a separate application that would take data in batches of around 1000 records and hit the web-service of the asp.net site. I'm just wondering will the app pool recycle while I'm hitting this web-service and stop my process?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure IIS so that the app pool recycles a lot there is a chance that this will be during a request. IIS will finish the request before it recycles. If you don't want to recycle the app pool you should change that setting.
If the request takes to much time you will get a time-out, but you can change these time-out settings (how depends on if you are using a WCF or ASMX web services).